# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/../feednew.php on line 161

Tags: php, innertext

```php
$item[$value['field_name']] = stripwhitespace(nv_convert(strip_tags($element->find($el[0],$el[1])->innertext)));
```

Throws back this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/../feednew.php on line 161**  >> >innertext
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code: `$element->find($el[0], $el[1])` does not return any object. You have to find out why. Maybe, your search parameters `$el[0]` and `$el[1]` are wrong, maybe the function itself is incomplete. We can't get more information from this line of code.